# Can xxx.com point to www.xxx.com on DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm having a problem with my DNS configuration. Everything is quite nice except for one big fact: xxx.com doesn't resolve to anything.

I have no idea how to config this, so any help would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't create a CNAME record for your xxx.com to point to www.xxx.com.

You'll have to create for an A record with the same ip-address as on your www A record.

According to [RFC 1912](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt)

> A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.  In
>   other words, if suzy.podunk.xx is an alias for sue.podunk.xx, you
>   can't also have an MX record for suzy.podunk.edu, or an A record, or
>   even a TXT record.  Especially do not try to combine CNAMEs and NS
>   records like this!:

```
       podunk.xx.      IN      NS      ns1
                       IN      NS      ns2
                       IN      CNAME   mary
       mary            IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

Comment: good point HBruijn

Comment: Well the thing is if I am to create an A record for abc.com, it would have to be on the NS for .com, and not on NS of abc.com. Correct?

Comment: NO. You would create it in the zone for abc.com on the abc.com name servers, not on the .COM root servers.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused how. How am I able to create a host without a name? As abc.com is the zone, how can I create an A record of abc.com in that zone? (there's no host name.)

Comment: It depends on the name server software for the exact syntax, in bind you would add a line like `abc.com.  IN  A  1.2.3.4` to your zone. The trailing `.` dot after the domainname indicates a FQDN and not a shorthand hostname to which bind should append the name of the zone.